Escape ">" character in Eclipse EMF serialization
I am serializing an EMF EObject to file.
This works fine and is all correct.
But: a third-party tool relies on escaping the > character, also for text fields. What is the cleanest way to do this? I would like to prevent post processing the serialized file. I could not find any export option which would enable this extended escaping.
